# Archive pagination - second page shows exactly the same posts

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, custom-post-type-archives

I have a loop to custom posts archive, but the second page shows exactly the same posts than the first page.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <?php
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'post_type' => 'work'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop
          get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-work', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;

    endif;?>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="marg--bottom-l text--center">
    <?php
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
    the_posts_pagination();

    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</div>
```

Do you know what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: pagination API calls always refer to the main query, have you considered modifying the main query via filters rather than replacing it? Remember, computers need to be told explicitly what to do, and your query mentions nothing about which page the user is on etc

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <?php
            $args = array( 
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post_type' => 'work',
                'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
            );

            $myposts = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>



            <?php single_term_title(); ?>
                <?php if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>

                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>

                <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marg--bottom-l text--center">
                <?php if (($myposts->max_num_pages) > 1) { ?>

                    <nav class="custom-pagination">
                        <?php echo pagination($myposts); ?>
                    </nav>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

And After this put below code in function.php file

```
function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_archive('project') ) {
    set_query_var('posts_per_page', 1);
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: can you explain why this fixes the problem? The OP won't get very far if you never explain what you changed and why